# Juju bundle deployment and local repository

Tags: juju

Is is possible to deploy bundles that contain charms from a local repository? I suspect using the commandline, it might be possible but the juju-gui has no idea where to find the local charms...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is correct. You can use local charms in a bundle if you use `juju-deployer` (`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:juju/stable; sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install juju-deployer`). After doing this you'll need to download the bundle you wish to deploy, modify it so that it just uses "charm" names:

```
bundle:
  service:
    charm: wordpress
```

instead of the fully qualified `cs:trusty/wordpress`. After this, set `JUJU_REPOSITORY` to your local charm repository and run `juju deployer` against your `bundles.yaml` file.